# jQuery hide(), delay() and clearTimeout() not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want if a user hovers over `.userNames`, `.details` should slide out after a little delay and also wants `.details` show `hide()` when the mouse leaves `.userNames`, after a little delay too. This is working. Now I want `.details` to stay if the mouse enters it but it still disappears.

**Obsv:** A good example of this is Facebook's user names when a mouse hovers them.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class = 'posts'>
<p class = 'userNames'> Yax </p>
<div class = 'details'> 
    <p> Full Name </p>
    <p> Birthday </p>
    <p> Age </p>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.details').hide();
    $(document).on('mouseenter', ".userNames", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.data($this, 'timer', setTimeout(function(){
            $this.parents('.posts').find('.details').slideDown(100);
        },900));
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', ".userNames", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parents('.posts').find('.details').delay(800).hide(100);
    });
    $(document).on('mouseenter', ".details", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $dataTime = $this.parents('.posts').find('.userNames');
        clearTimeout($.data($dataTime, 'timer'));
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', ".details", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.hide();
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rvaDV/1/

Comment: also try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rvaDV/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Thank you loadz. It worked like magic. But which of the two is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.details').hide();
    $(document).on('mouseenter', ".userNames", function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $post = $this.closest('.posts');
        $post.data('timer', setTimeout(function () {
            $post.find('.details').stop(true, true).slideDown(100);
        }, 900));
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', ".userNames", function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $post = $this.closest('.posts');
        clearTimeout($post.data('timer'));
        $post.data('timer', setTimeout(function () {
            $post.find('.details').stop(true, true).delay(800).hide(100);
        }, 900));
    });
    $(document).on('mouseenter', ".details", function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $post = $this.closest('.posts');
        clearTimeout($post.data('timer'));
        $this.stop(true, true)
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', ".details", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rvaDV/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works and simplifies your jQuery a lot:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.details').hide();
    $('.userNames').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.details').delay(900).slideDown(100);
    });

    $('.userNames').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.details').delay(800).hide(100);
    });

    $('.details').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true);
    });

    $('.details').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).hide(100);
    });
});
```

[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nArNN/).